# Paste into next empty row of another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

The below code, when a user logs an issue into a form, will log in the appropriate issue tab.

Once the team has completed the issue and marks it as "Complete & Verified", I want to move that issue (row) out of the current tab into the "5. Complete & Verified" tab.

The issue is, say there are 9 rows of data in the current tab, the macro is pasting the row into the 9th row of the "5. Complete & Verified" tab.

I am trying to paste one after the other starting in B2. I am also trying to Paste the tab name into column 1 (column A) as an identifier.

```vb
Sub Complete()

    ActiveSheet.Activate
    Dim objWS As Worksheet
    Set objWS = ActiveSheet

    Dim intLastRowSrc As Long
    intLastRowSrc = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ActiveSheet.Activate
    Dim intLastRowSDes As Long
    intLastRowSDes = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    Dim r As Long

    For r = 2 To intLastRowSrc

        If objWS.Cells(r, "R") = "Complete & Verified" Then

           Sheets("5. Complete & Verified").Range("B" & intLastRowSDes & ":T" & intLastRowSDes).Value = objWS.Range("A" & r & ":S" & r).Value
           objWS.Rows(r).Delete
           Sheets("5. Complete & Verified").Cells(intLastRowSDes, 1) = ws1.Name
           intLastRowSrc = intLastRowSrc - 1
           intLastRowSDes = intLastRowSDes + 1 'Issue - I need it to paste into next row with now data in 5. tab

        End If

    Next

    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need adjusted to work as (I think) you want things to work.

Firstly, set references to the source and destination worksheets and use them directly rather than naming each time.

Secondly you don't need to `Activate` any of the worksheets, so let's remove those

Thirdly if you are looking to delete rows within a `for` loop, always start at the bottom of your data range and move up- otherwise when you delete row 21 and 22 moves up, your loop will completely ignore the fact that 22 moved up without getting checked and you will miss rows

Fourthly, just grab the destination row from inside the loop rather than try to increment the count

Fifthly, you are setting column 1 on your destination sheet to `ws1.name` but you never define it, so I've replaced that with a reference to the source worksheet name.

If any of this doesn't make sense, drop a comment below and I'll try to explain better.

```
Sub Complete()

Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
Set sourceWS = ActiveSheet
Dim destWS As Worksheet
Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5. Complete & Verified")

Dim intLastRowSrc As Long
intLastRowSrc = sourceWS.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim intLastRowSDes As Long
Dim r As Long

For r = intLastRowSrc to 2 Step -1

    If sourceWS.Cells(r, "R") = "Complete & Verified" Then
       intLastRowSDes = destWS.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
       destWS.Range("B" & intLastRowSDes & ":T" & intLastRowSDes).Value = sourceWS.Range("A" & r & ":S" & r).Value
       sourceWS.Rows(r).Delete
       destWS.Cells(intLastRowSDes, 1) = sourceWS.Name

    End If

Next

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Dave! This worked. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

Dave posted his answer while I was working on it. While it will work, if I'm not mistaken, and that may well be the case, the items will be copied in reverse order to the new destination sheet. If order is important you may what to try using a Do/Loop as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Complete()

Dim lRow         As Long
Dim shtWS        As Worksheet
Dim shtDest      As Worksheet
Dim lLastRowSDes As Long

'*** Don't use ActiveSheet rather specify the name
'*** If called from more than one sheet pass as parameter.
Set shtWS = WorkSheets("your sheet name here")
set shtDst = Worksheets("5.Complete & Verified")


lLastRowSDes = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", _
                 searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                 searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1

lRow = 2  'Set Starting Row

Do 
    If shtWS.Cells(lRow, "R") = "Complete & Verified" Then
       shtWS.Range("B" & lRow & ":T" & lRow).Copy
       shtDst.Range("B" & lLastRowSDes).Paste
       shtWS.Rows(lRow).Delete
       '*** Note we don't increment counter as next row moves up to current lRow position!
       shtDst.Cells(lLastRowSDes, 1) = shtWS.Name
       lLastRowSDes = lLastRowSDes + 1 
    Else
      lRow = lRow + 1  'Increment Row Counter
    End If

    
Loop Until (shtWS.Cells(lRow,"B").Value = "")
```

You'll notice I used Copy/Paste as I've never seen the syntax of assigning one range to another like that, very neat! So you could just replace the copy/paste lines with that one.

FYI: code not tested!

HTH

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the row is not pasting starting in row 2. As you mentioned, I think the "Active Sheet" is throwing something off.

Comment: when setting `lLastRowSDes` you should be using `shtDst` rather than `ActiveSheet` to get the first blank row in the destination sheet.  This will be why it's not pasting in row 2 on the destination as @CBK1234 notes